# Failed To Add Table Adapter in XSD

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xsd, tableadapter

I am running with an weird issue, I have an existing SXD project in my solution. I am just trying to add a new table adapter to it but after I am done with all the steps (specifying connection string, SQL query etc); hit finish it fails with error

> Failed To Add Table Adapter -- Unable to find connection string
>   "testcon" for object settings.

But when I check the `setting.settings` file OR `App.config` I can see the `testcon` connection string is present right there and it's correct. Then what's wrong?

Tried searching in MSDN forums (AND) Google but no luck.

Have anyone faced this issue before? Any idea how can I fix this? IS this a VS Bug?

NOTE: I am working in VS2010 SP1.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly not sure whether it's a VS bug or not but I resolved it.

Somehow, felt that the connection string under "Settings.Setting" file have been messed (OR) corrupted. So ended up removing all the connection string and recreating them afresh. It's did worked perfectly.

Hope this helps to someone.

Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me. The connection strings in the legacy app I encountered this in were in both App.config and Settings.settings. I'd been modifying them in App.config and reloading them in Settings.settings per the Settings.settings prompt saying they'd been modified in App.config and asking if I wanted to update them. Removing them from Settings.settings and adding them back manually finally got rid of the error.

Comment: 5 years and a million tears later, there is no solution to this Visual Studio bug. Even after deleting all the settings. This is why I'd rather create my own classes - it takes 10X longer to create, but 1000X faster to debug!